# Is "overly" necessary?

Tags: word-choice

Somehow, *overly* never struck me as a cromulent word.  *Over* is already an adverb.  You can write “This sentence is over-long.”  Is there really an advantage to writing “This sentence is overly long”?

Is there a context in which *overly* is right and *over* is not?

(Edit: already an *adverb*.)

Comment: *overly* is in more dictionaries than *cromulent* ...

Comment: @GEdgar: So by implication, *overly* is a more ***cromulent*** word than *cromulent*.

Comment: Well, most people are not over (sic) enthusiastic at your suggestion that _overly_ is unnecessary!

Answer (score 3):

*Overly* is an adverb (not an adjective) and is [defined as](http://www.wordnik.com/words/overly):

> **adv.** To an excessive degree: *overly protective*

One of the jobs of an adverb is to modify an adjective, which is what it is doing in your sentence, "This sentence is overly long."

*Over* has many [different meanings,](http://www.wordnik.com/words/over) but it does not share the meaning that *overly* has when it is used as an adverb.